# Apple MacBook Pro with Touch Bar gets error mesage when reinstalling macOS High Sierra: Could not establish pre start volume for APFS installation

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, apfs

I get the following error message when reinstalling macOS High Sierra: Could not establish pre-start volume for APFS installation.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Make a backup of your data, then delete all volumes, containers and partitions and try again.